# SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file while starting Nginx

Tags: nginx, debian, ssl

While I'm starting nginx, there is appearing:

```
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file("/etc/ssl/xxx.crt") failed (SSL:)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Cert files are in /etc/ssl and they have all permissions. It was working for 3 months and now i tried to just restart nginx.. How to fix this? It is very important for me now.

sites-enabled/default config:

```
   root /usr/share/nginx;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
       server_name localhost;
            ssl on;
                ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/xxx.crt;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/cert.key;
```

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer (and accept it if it's the best answer), instead of editing it into the question. The site will keep trying to attract answers to your unanswered question forever otherwise

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed this! Reason was breaking line between chain and ----END OF CHAIN--- in the end of cert chain file. I don't know why it does work before restarting nginx.**